# Error al compilar en C++ por el nombre del archivo

Tags: c++, compilar, compilador, ejecutar

tengo un archivo `.cpp` que se llama `10.-Matriz.cpp` que al momento de compilarlo me sale un error, pero cuando le cambié el nombre a `Matriz.cpp`, funcionó correctamente.

**¿Como podría solucionarlo para tener archivos `.cpp` enumerados.?**

**¿Por qué sucede esto?***

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Procura ser lo más descriptivo posible; eso incluye mensajes de error completos. Todo, en lo posible, como texto y no como imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas Windows 10 o anterior los nombres de archivos y carpetas no pueden contener: **"  \ / : * ? " < > | .  "**

En tu caso está usando el punto, y el punto no se puede usar, es exclusivo de las extensiones de archivo.

Si usas GNU/Linux el caso es diferente, salvo **'\0'** y **'/'** puedes usar lo que quieras, porque GNU/Linux identifica los archivos por el contenido y no por la extensión. Como te da error supongo que utilizas Win10. Elimina el punto y ya estaría.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por el carácter guión. Prueba a poner el archivo entre comillas dobles o ha quitar el punto guión.

Comment: Amigo, vas a poder poner comentarios cuando tengas mas reputacion. Porfavor manten el area de respuestas para las respuestas